# Create partial sublists by index, discarding some data [(x,y,z),...] to [(x,y),...]

Tags: python-2.7, nested-lists

I got a `list1` which has N items in each item it has `(x,y,z)`. For z in `list2`, I need to create a new list which has items from `list1` with only `(x,y)` this need to be done for `list3`, `list4` too.

```
list1 = [(1250, 1442, 0), (1280, 1655, 1), (1029, 1680, 2), (624, 1573, 3), (732, 1159, 4), (1530, 1634, 5), (1885, 1628, 6), (2152, 1834, 7), (1252, 2459, 8), (1309, 3023, 9), (1376, 3585, 10), (1571, 2388, 11), (1682, 2952, 12), (1686, 3579, 13), (1184, 1391, 14), (1291, 1382, 15), (1117, 1440, 16), (1361, 1400, 17)]

list2 = [0,1,14,15,16,17]

list3 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11]

list4 = [9,10,12,13]
```

For example, `list5` which is between `list1` and `list2` looks like

```
list5 = [(1250, 1442),(1280, 1655),(1184, 1391)......]
```

Can anyone suggest a fast way to do it? Thank you

Comment: Umm, is the `z` coordinate always the index of the tuple in `list1` or is that just a coincidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
def getXYfromIndex(l, indexes):
    """Returns x,y from bigger list 'l' containing (x,y,z).
    Uses only those elements (by index) of 'l' that are in 'indexes'"""

    # list comprehension: returns x,y for each index in 'l' that is in 'indexes'
    return [(x,y) for x,y,_ in (l[i] for i  in indexes)]


list1 = [(1250, 1442, 0), (1280, 1655, 1), (1029, 1680, 2), (624, 1573, 3), (732, 1159, 4), 
         (1530, 1634, 5), (1885, 1628, 6), (2152, 1834, 7), (1252, 2459, 8), 
         (1309, 3023, 9), (1376, 3585, 10), (1571, 2388, 11), (1682, 2952, 12), 
         (1686, 3579, 13), (1184, 1391, 14), (1291, 1382, 15), (1117, 1440, 16), 
         (1361, 1400, 17)]

list2 = [0,1,14,15,16,17]

list3 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11]

list4 = [9,10,12,13]

print(getXYfromIndex(list1,list2)) # use list5 = getXYfromIndex(list1,list2)
print(getXYfromIndex(list1,list3)) # to work with those (x,y) - I just print them
print(getXYfromIndex(list1,list4))
```

Output:

```
[(1250, 1442), (1280, 1655), (1184, 1391), (1291, 1382), (1117, 1440), (1361, 1400)]

[(1029, 1680), (624, 1573), (732, 1159), (1530, 1634), (1885, 1628), (2152, 1834), 
 (1252, 2459), (1571, 2388)]

[(1309, 3023), (1376, 3585), (1682, 2952), (1686, 3579)]
```

Comment: In some cases, the list1 doesn't have z of list2 in such cases it's returning error. Instead of error can it return the z that exits?

Comment: @the_guy Try changing the method to `return [(x,y) for x,y,_ in (l[i] for i in indexes if i < len(l))]` - this should eleminate all indexes that are too big to be asked from l